# Convert USB powered lamp to a remote controlled lamp

Tags: electrical, lighting, lamp

I have a bedside lamp that I own which is powered via USB and has a On/Off switch at the back. This is fairly inconvenient to turn on and off from bed.

Is there any way to adjust the hardware of this lamp to add on a remote control functionality to turn it on rather than a manual switch on the lamp itself?

The exact lamp I have is found [here](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00JE8ANME)

Comment: Not without adding significant amounts of circuitry.

Answer (score 2):

The lamp has no brain; it's just using USB as a power source. You would have to add some form of receiver and control circuit either between lamp and USB, or between USB and wall.

Comment: I agree and understand. That is what I needed help with, I am not sure what exact receiver I need to look for that I can place between the USB and the wall

Comment: Any commercially available remote lamp switch should work, if the USB adapter is plugged directly into the wall. If this is being powered thru a computer, you may have to build your own solution.

Comment: How about something like http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B007Y7D8Z6 would this be safe considering the lamp itself would be always On in terms of it's manual switch.

Comment: @rp7 Yes that would work. However, where is this USB lamp currently plugged in to? If it works in a computer (DC power), it might not work from the wall socket (AC power)

Comment: Yes - it goes into the wall via an ordinary USB wall socket. Thanks!!

Comment: If the 5v is coming directly from the wall (a "USB socket") rather than house current feeding a USB power brick, you'll probably need to homebrew a solution.